# How do you grab an element and dynamically add or remove styles from it in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm coming from the world of React and trying to translate a component into React Native. In react we can easily grab an element with `useRef` and then add or remove classes.

Is there a way to easily translate this to react native as I see when I inspect the `current` property of the `<Text>` element it looks nothing like an html element.

Here is the file I'm trying to convert:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';

// styles
import styles from './whiteTextReveal.module.css';

export const WhiteTextReveal = props => {
    // props
    const {text, duration, callback} = props;
    // local
    const leftMask = useRef(null);
    const rightMask = useRef(null);
    const textRef = useRef(null);
    const animationTimeouts = useRef([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        reveal();
        return () => {
            animationTimeouts.current.map(val => clearTimeout(val));
        }
    }, [text]);

    function reveal() {
        let time = 0;
        // reveal first white masks
        const timeout1 = setTimeout(() => {
            // cleanup if called successively
            textRef.current.classList.remove(styles.shrink);
            leftMask.current.classList.remove(styles.moveRight);
            rightMask.current.classList.remove(styles.moveLeft);

            leftMask.current.classList.add(styles.moveLeft);
            rightMask.current.classList.add(styles.moveRight);
        }, 1000*time);
        animationTimeouts.current = [...animationTimeouts.current, timeout1];

        // reveal text behind first white mask
        time = time + .8; // come from the css file .mask.left.moveLeft
        const timeout2 = setTimeout(() => {
            textRef.current.classList.remove(styles.hide);
            leftMask.current.classList.remove(styles.moveLeft);
            rightMask.current.classList.remove(styles.moveRight);

            leftMask.current.classList.add(styles.moveRight);
            rightMask.current.classList.add(styles.moveLeft);
        }, 1000*time);
        animationTimeouts.current = [...animationTimeouts.current, timeout2];

        // move mask to cover text again
        time = time + .5 + duration; // come from the css file .mask.left.moveRight
        const timeout3 = setTimeout(() => {
            textRef.current.classList.add(styles.shrink);
            const timeout4 = setTimeout(() => {
                textRef.current.classList.add(styles.hide);
                callback()
            }, .7*1000);
            animationTimeouts.current = [...animationTimeouts.current, timeout4];
        }, time*1000);
        animationTimeouts.current = [...animationTimeouts.current, timeout3];

    }
    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <span ref={textRef} className={`${styles.text} ${styles.hide}`}>{text}</span>
            <div ref={leftMask} className={`${styles.mask} ${styles.left}`}/>
            <div ref={rightMask} className={`${styles.mask} ${styles.right}`}/>
        </div>
    )
};
```

This is a text animation reveal that paints a white strip over text, slides back, and the scales the text to 0 before telling the parent component it finished.

As you can see from these lines:

```
textRef.current.classList.remove(styles.shrink);
leftMask.current.classList.remove(styles.moveRight);
rightMask.current.classList.remove(styles.moveLeft);
```

I am grabbing the ref and then removing classes. And the lines that follow after add those classes back in specific ways.

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but animations are completely different in RN. As you noticed, there's no html under the hood, and instructions have to be sent to native components. Look into the built-in Animated API or Reanimated.

Comment: Like Abe said, in react native you need to use the Animated API to generate the animation styles. So to be able to give effective help, seeing what's  happening in whiteTextReveal.module.css is necessary